# How can I get entries where a date is within a dynamic date range?

Tags: templating, elementcriteriamodel, datetime

```
{% set params = {
      section : 'events',
      order : 'eventStartDate asc',
      eventStartDate : '>=' ~ now,
      limit : row.itemsPerPage.value
} %}
```

I am trying to pull a set of event entries for a basic event calendar and I'm trying to figure out the syntax for the eventStartDate parameter to have it pull starting with the current date and ending with a value of the current date + 1 month, 3 months, or 6 months depending on the value set in another field named eventDateRange. I need help with how to write that as a command like the one listed above.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so in the end you’d want your “startDate” custom field parameter to be a string in this format:

```
'and, >= 2017-08-04T05:00:00+08:00, < 2017-08-11T04:59:59+08:00'
```

I’m outputting a format for the dates that includes the time and timezone, so that we are able to define when exactly events are being refreshed. To do that I’m using the `date` filter (otherwise Twig outputs dates in `Y-m-d` format).

Here’s how you compose the final string including the value from the Global Set, that I am simply concatenating to a string that I pass into the `date_modify` filter.

```
{% set var = myGlobalSet.myNumbersField %}

{% set rangeStart = now|date_modify('5:00')|date('c') %}
{% set rangeEnd = now|date_modify('5:00 +' ~ var ~ ' weeks')|date('c') %}

{% set startDateParam = 'and, >=' ~ rangeStart ~ ', <' ~ rangeEnd %}
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks. Just to help me understand, are the ('5:00') and the date|('c') setting the time zone?

Comment: Yeah, `date_modify('5:00')` overrides the time and set it to 5:00. `date('c')` outputs the DateTime object in ISO8601 format, the one I posted above which has timezone info included.

Comment: ok so if I don't want to override the time to 5:00 and use the time set on the event I just leave off the date_modify('5:00')?

Comment: It’s the `now` time that is being overridden, but yep you don’t need to do it and it will immediately hide events as soon as they started.